# Is it valid to use LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin in DRF APIview?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

Here I am using `LoginRequiredMixin` and `PermissionRequiredMixin` in DRF view instead of built-in permissions. Is it ok use them with DRF API views?

```
class UserAPI(**LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin,***generics.ListAPIView*):
    queryset = User.objects.filter(user_type="BRANCH_MANAGER")
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_required = ["accounts.view_branchmanager"]
    login_url = "api-auth/login/"
```

Comment: It is *okay* (I wouldn't do that) to use them if you are using *session authentication*, else, do not.

Comment: @JPG , Django uses session authentication and I am using loginrequiredmixin as well. So, what about token authentication?